# Python OS.environ

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I have set environmental `PATH` on my unix machine for user `x` to
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/home/x/.local/bin:/home/x/bin`

But, when I execute `python os. environ` using the `x` user.Below is the result
`/usr/bin:/bin:/home/x/.local/bin:/home/x/bin`

Why sbin path is not shown using the os. environ, any leads on why this mismatch in behaviour?

Comment: I suspect that you aren't executing `python` from the shell session with the longer `PATH` in its environment.

Comment: Where and how are you changing `PATH`